# what is the original location for asp.net request?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to determine when a user opens a link in my website through an email that I sent. What would be the best way to do this? I know I can add a querystring parameter , &OpenedTroughEmail=1 or something.

Comment: Addint the parameter to the query string is a good way to go about it. What is it that you don't like about that idea?

Answer (score 1):

A query string parameter is the usual way to do this. Just look at the links in any newsletter from Microsoft or just about anyone else. You will see query string parameters which identify the link as being part of a specific market 'campaign' or strategy.

This is really the only way to do it since you have no idea what kind of email client people might be using so even something like site referral and google analytics wouldn't necessarily yield any results.

Bear in mind that even the query string parameter is not 100% guaranteed to work. It's still possible for a user to simply eyeball your link and then just manually navigate to the site by typing in your website address. You could, perhaps, get round this by making the link itself do something specific, like give a promotion code or some other otherwise non-navigable content.